# sed or perl replacing sub string only, with the result of other command

Tags: perl, sed

How, by one-liner sed or perl, to replace a sub string only, with the result of other command execution, in the middle of full line string e.g:

```
$ cat f
iiiiiii
OOO=dd=XXX
uuuuuuu
```

it's clear in string line with distinct substring patterned `=dd=` would be captured to be executed by a command, say, `type -p`

e.g. sed is:

```
$ sed -E 's/^O+=([a-z]\w+)=X+$/type -p \1/e' f
```

but the result is only the command execution's one, with no complete two adjacent strings, i.e. fails to get the correct solution

```bash
OOO=/usr/bin/dd=XXX
```

So help out how to accomplish up to the correct solution by sed or perl (or both if being so generous)

Comment: Try using `=[^=]+=` instead of `=[a-z]\w+=`

Comment: It is unclear what you want your end result to be

Comment: Requiring a "one-liner" is counter-productive. Any wretched command can be crammed onto a single line if you insist, but it's usually a bad idea. Put it in a script or a shell function and then that's your one-liner (or even one-worder).

Comment: Are the 0s and the Xs required part of the pattern? Should they be in the end result?

Comment: Very few seds will understand you want `\w` to mean `[[:alnum:]_]`. Probably only GNU sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use more capture groups and tweaking of replacement string to get it right like this:

```bash
sed -E 's/^(O+=)([a-z]\w*)(=X+)$/echo "\1$(type -p \2)\3"/e' f

iiiiiii
OOO=/usr/bin/dd=XXX
uuuuuuu
```

We have 3 capture groups:

- `^`: Start
- `(O+=)`: Match 1+ of `O` followed by a `=`. Capture this in 1st group
- `([a-z]\w*)`: Match `[a-z]` followed by 0 or more word characters. Capture this in 2nd group
- `(=X+)`: Match `=` followed by 1+ of `X`. Capture this in 3rd group
- `$`: End
- `echo "\1$(type -p \2)\3` is used to put `\1` followed by `type -p \2` followed by `\3` in the substitution.

### [**Online Demo**](https://ideone.com/zzzewE)

As commented below by @TLP, this command can be made more generic by using:

```bash
sed -E 's/^([^=]+=)(\w+)(=.*)$/echo "\1$(type -p \2)\3"/e' f
```

Comment: If the 0s and Xs are not part of the required pattern, they should be ignored, rather than hard coded.

Comment: Thanks @TLP I have added a more generic command for that

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here's a Perl solution.

```
perl -ne 's/^(O+=)(.*)(=X+)$/ $p = qx(type -p $2), chomp $p,
   sprintf "%s%s%s", $1, $p, $3 /e and print' file
```

Comment: You're complicating things by including the prefix and suffix in the match. If you don't, your code reduces to the following: `perl -ne's/^O+=\K(.*)(?==X+$)/ $p = \`type -p $&\`; chomp $p; $p /e'`

Comment: Replaced chomp: `perl -ne's{^O+=\K(.*)(?==X+$)}{ \`type -p $&\` =~ s/\n\z//r }e'`

Comment: But apparently the OP wants to keep $1 and $3 around the result from `type -p`

Comment: The snippets I posted do exactly the same as yours. They're just far less wordy.